# Showing something my text instead of error message text while data is being loaded in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is that possible to replace an error message text with my own text?

For example, if you go to https://o-canada.shinyapps.io/vitals
you will get to see rather discouraging error message text:

"An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification"

while the App is loading the data.

Is that possible to suppress this error message so it is not shown to user, and even better to replace it with my own text message like (eg. "Please wait until the data is loaded") ?

Comment: Use [`tryCatch`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html) to catch the error where it is occurring, then optionally show a modal popup with what you need (perhaps from [`shinyalerts`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyalert/index.html), though not required).

Comment: Add a `req` statement in your render event so the red error will not show up.

Comment: In addition to using `req()` to prevent error message if no input is loaded, you can also look at the function `cleave()` in the package [`sever`](https://sever.john-coene.com/cleave/) to customize error messages